# how to use rancher api to save the Host Registration URL

Tags: rancher

[image]

How can i save the base url use method like curl, or use rancher api rather than click save on the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rancher 1.x, you shouldn't need to do that. If you use the API to create a host registration token, that value will get automatically set and will stop asking in the gui:

```
$ curl -s -X POST  -H 'Accept: application/json'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{"name":"local"}' "https://your-rancher-server/v1/projects/1a5/registrationtokens"
{ "id:"1c2"..... }
```

That created a registration token for local hosts, now fetch the `docker run` command to use on the hosts:

```
$ curl -s -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:9999/v1/registrationtokens/1c2 | jq -r '.command'
docker run --rm ...
```

The side-effect is that the server's URL is now set from the url you used to create the registration token.